# Template inheritance error in Django with TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-templates

[image]base.html and child html file are in one directory app/templates/app:
lead_list.html

```
{% extends "leads/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'leads:lead-create' %}">Create a new Lead</a>

    <hr />
    <h1>This is all of our leads</h1>
    {% for lead in leads %}
        <div class="lead">
            <a href="{% url 'leads:lead-detail' lead.pk %}">{{ lead.first_name }} {{ lead.last_name }}</a>. Age: {{ lead.age }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DJCRM</title>
    <style>
        .lead {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 6px;
            padding-right: 6px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Lead, Agent
from .forms import LeadForm, LeadModelForm

def lead_list(request):
    leads = Lead.objects.all()
    context = {
        "leads": leads
    }
    return render(request, "lead_list.html", context)
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I am getting the error with django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: lead_list.html
I think I have done everything right and compared with documentation but could not find my error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a *filetree* where your templates are stored?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I uploaded the filetree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render the template with:

```
def lead_list(request):
    context = {
        'leads': Lead.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'leads/lead_list.html', context)
```

The `APP_DIRS` setting means that Django will look into the `templates/` directories of the apps, but since no such directory contains a `lead_list.html` file directly, it raises an error. There is however such template in a `leads` directory in the template directory.